# pending contract status after i changed my free app to paid app in app store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I had a free app which was released and ready to sale some days back on app store.Now i made it a paid app by setting 0.99 dollars .Now my status is changed to pending contract.What does this status mean?.what is the procedure after that and how much time it will take to get approved again??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Login to itunesconnect.
2. Goto Contracts,Tax and Banking, there you
   can see "iOS Paid Applications" contract.
3. Add the necessary info
   there, then your app will be automatically approved.

Comment: you mean i have to go for request button under ios paid application section

Answer (score 5):

From this Apple [FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html) :

What happens if I do not renew my iOS Developer Program membership?

> Once your membership expires, your apps will no longer be available on
>   the App Store and you will lose the ability to submit new apps. You
>   will lose access to pre-release software, the Apple Developer Forums,
>   Developer Technical Support, and the Certificate Utility. In addition,
>   your existing iOS Distribution certificates will be revoked and
>   invalidated. Finally, if you enrolled in the program as a company, you
>   will lose the ability to manage your development team.
>
> You will, however, retain your status as a Registered Apple Developer
>   and will have access to free development resources.
>
> In order to conserve your app on the AppStore, you must renew your iOS
>   Developer Program.

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 4):

You need to fill information in "Contracts,Tax and Banking" section by login to iTunesConnect. In that, once you fill your banking information then your app will be convert into paid app.

Cheers!

Comment: i have to fill the details under contract type iAd network also ???.I dont have a iAd set up in my app

Comment: Just fill it even if you don't have iAd in your app. Because, in future, when you add iAd in any of your app, then apple come to know that, you also have iad contract.

Comment: It will take some time. By not that much. May be 1 day.

Answer (score 2):

For Paid Application you have to fill up Paid contract first then only the Paid Applications to be allowed on the store.

There is No Other Procedure after changing price tier if your Paid App Contract is already done It will not take much time to change in store sometimes it takes half day or 1 day.

Hope this Helps.